# Accessing data outside (.then) promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

**Goal**: Make 2 different get requests and use the data together from the two requests.

**The Issue**: I need to use the the data outside of .then({}) as I can use it for my purpose.

Following the simplified version of what im trying to do.

```
function main(){
  const data1 = getData(URL1).then((data) => {
      console.log(data) //I have access to data here
    }
 
 const data2 = getData(URL2).then((data) => {
      console.log(data) //I have access to data here
    }
  

   console.log(data1) // I get Promise { <pending> }
   console.log(data2) // Same as above

   <Do something with data1 and data2 here>

  }





  async function getData(url){
      let data = (await axios.get(url)).data
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It has to happen inside of the function you pass to `.then`. You can have an instance of a previously declared higher scoped Object in the `.then` function, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function main(){
  const data1 = await getData(URL1);
 
 const data2 = await getData(URL2);
  

   console.log(data1)
   console.log(data2)

   <Do something with data1 and data2 here>

  }





  async function getData(url){
      return (await axios.get(url)).data
   }
```

Comment: This works but I don't understand why we have to make both functions async await.

Comment: @HarrySingh `async` means the function will return a `Promise`, `await` means `xxx().then()` in a sync way. `await` will block the code and wait async function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data1 = getData(URL1);
const data2 = getData(URL2)

const data = Promise.all([data1, data2]).then(([result1, result2]) => {
   // do stuff
   // remember to return something or data won't equal anything
})
```

or if you are using async await

```js
const data1 = getData(URL1);
const data2 = getData(URL2)

const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([data1, data2]);
// do stuff
```

Comment: result1, and result2 is still a Promise.